# #1054 - Unknown column 'FOTO' in 'order clause'

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un archivo .sql que lo importo en phpmyadmin. Me carga correctamente todas las tablas, pero cuando clickeo sobre la tabla "vehiculos" me dice el siguiente mensaje: #1054 - Unknown column 'FOTO' in 'order clause'. No tengo en ninguna tabla la columna FOTO, he probado a buscar en TODO el documento .sql de la base de datos la palabra "FOTO-foto" pero 0 encontrados.

Código de la tabla vehiculo:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS OSMARENTCARS;
CREATE DATABASE OSMARENTCARS;
USE OSMARENTCARS;


CREATE TABLE MARCA(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(20),
    WEB VARCHAR(30),
    TLF_CONTACTO VARCHAR(12),
    CONSTRAINT PK_MARCA PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
);

INSERT INTO MARCA (DESCRIPCION, WEB, TLF_CONTACTO) VALUES 
("FERRARI", "WWW.FERRARI.COM", "123456789"), 
("FIAT", "WWW.FIAT.COM", "235684791"), 
("FORD", "WWW.FORD.COM", "678678678"),
("HONDA", "WWW.HONDA.COM", "908476321"), 
("HYUNDAI", "WWW.HYUNDAI.COM", "697804157"),
("LAMBORGHINI", "WWW.LAMBORGHINI.COM", "951784662"), 
("MITSUBISHI", "WWW.MITSUBISHI.COM", "987354118"),
("OPEL", "WWW.OPEL.COM", "942668877"),
("RENAULT", "WWW.RENAULT.COM", "958476321"), 
("SEAT", "WWW.SEAT.COM", "697899957"),
("TOYOTA", "WWW.TOYOTA.COM", "951784662"), 
("VOLKSWAGEN", "WWW.VOLKSWAGEN.COM", "987354118");




CREATE TABLE VEHICULO(
    BASTIDOR VARCHAR(30),
    COLOR VARCHAR(10),
    MATRICULA VARCHAR(7),
    MARCA INT,
    MODELO VARCHAR(50), 
    POTENCIA INT,
    CONSUMO DECIMAL(4,2),
    FECHA_FABRICACION DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_VEHICULO PRIMARY KEY (BASTIDOR),
    CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICULO FOREIGN KEY (MARCA) REFERENCES MARCA(ID)
);

INSERT INTO VEHICULO VALUES 
("JKSFLS23B342988", "BLANCO", "2593HBD", 1, "CALIFORNIA", 389, 13.1, "2007/11/03"), 
("JUUS234FWER23RW", "AMARILLO", "4141HGG", 2, "PUNTO", 85, 7.2, "2008/10/12"), 
("KMOWEMFIF93223F", "VERDE", "8862DCD", 3, "KA", 87, 8.8, "2004/05/23"), 
("FWEF232342AAAAA", "METALIZADO", "9876CDS", 4, "JAZZ", 93, 8.8, "2003/10/07"), 
("AAAA3AFKGUEG339", "BLANCO", "6295JLS", 5, "I10", 87, 7.9, "2015/12/01"), 
("PKOKI9UW45R233E", "GRIS", "1137HAA", 6, "CENTENARIO", 270, 11.2, "2007/12/06"), 
("FERFFER34534533", "ROJO", "6995DDS", 7, "SPACE_STAR", 110, 9.7, "2004/06/04"), 
("XVXCV8X97XCV989", "NARANJA", "1333HAC", 8, "CORSA", 72, 6.4, "2008/12/12"),
("KH4578KROGKRO44", "ROJO", "2522HCC", 9, "TWINGO", 80, 6.7, "2007/11/02"), 
("LKJOGTUXTD34635", "AMARILLO", "4111HBB", 10, "IBIZA", 88, 7.2, "2008/10/13"), 
("HGYUGMÑ35636531", "VERDE", "3062DCA", 11, "AYGO", 103, 7.6, "2004/05/23"), 
("LLSERASJK222823", "AZUL", "9223FBF", 12, "TIGUAN", 103, 7.7, "2006/10/11"), 
("KEYAO3242342020", "GRIS", "6211BAK", 1, "SERGIO", 356, 12.5, "2002/04/02"), 
("LKOJU234234234J", "BLANCO", "1193HAC", 2, "PANDA", 80, 6.3, "2007/11/04"), 
("OJIO2J34IOJ2423", "ROJO","6945DRE", 3, "FIESTA", 85, 6.8, "2004/06/03"), 
("JPKLKMKJH2U3424", "NARANJA", "9344AAP", 4, "CIVIC", 90, 7.4, "2001/03/19"),
("MKNOKN38820020F", "ROJO", "0003AGF", 5, "I20", 89, 8.1, "2001/08/02"), 
("LKJAWE342422111", "NEGRO", "7667GFR", 6, "HURACAN", 245, 10.7, "2008/10/12"), 
("KJIOHUHJ6933322", "VERDE",  "3434GHI", 7, "ASX", 139, 9.1, "2004/07/23"), 
("KJRWQQ0NN4M1119", "AZUL",  "2228CKK", 8, "ZAFIRA", 89, 7.8, "2006/10/11"), 
("ABC3DE559QJK444", "GRIS",  "7188ADS", 9, "MEGANE", 95, 7.6, "2001/03/24"), 
("BREAOELUHN34397", "NEGRO", "9995FFT", 10, "TOLEDO", 85, 7.0, "2010/12/04"), 
("IUERWIK5688ASDE", "AMARILLO", "4419CII", 11, "YARIS", 100, 7.4, "2005/06/18"), 
("KEEY777ARDD4880", "BLANCO", "6330HDP", 12, "POLO", 100, 7.2, "2009/12/17"),
("WEFWEFWF9234242", "BLANCO", "5593HID", 1, "FF", 390, 15.1, "2008/09/05"), 
("EFWEFWWER234999", "AMARILLO", "0041HQA", 2, "FREEMONT", 90, 7.9, "2008/11/11"), 
("KPOKPIOHWF56561", "VERDE", "2262DCE", 3, "FOCUS", 85, 9.0, "2004/05/21"), 
("ASDASÑLKPOK2342", "METALIZADO", "2876CFS", 4, "NSX", 100, 9.4, "2003/09/19"), 
("EFEWKPOKPK23424", "BLANCO", "6995JTR", 5, "ELANDRA", 90, 7.9, "2016/04/04"), 
("PKPOK38BVA023J0", "GRIS", "9937HAL", 6, "AVENTADOR", 305, 12.1, "2007/07/28"), 
("ODKHVIRIRED9839", "GRANATE", "6905DWS", 7, "OUTLANDER", 140, 10.1, "2004/08/18"), 
("ASDERLDI4DJ459W", "NARANJA", "8883HEC", 8, "KARL", 80, 6.6, "2008/12/12"),
("LKEEKKIQ4822292", "ROJO", "2529DCM", 9, "CLIO", 75, 6.3, "2004/08/29"), 
("LKEUENCIEMSOWJ3", "AMARILLO", "0011HMM", 10, "LEON", 85, 7.1, "2009/10/13"), 
("ITJTNRVRNXO0099", "METALIZADO", "8762DNA", 11, "AURIS", 95, 7.4, "2004/05/30"), 
("LAKWYEBDMCIWU2N", "GRIS", "9000FOF", 12, "TOURAN", 115, 8.3, "2007/10/11"), 
("LKEUDNMDOJN3333", "GRIS", "8211AAK", 1, "GTC4LUSSO", 370, 14.1, "2002/04/02"), 
("ALAO3AOKEMLEO3K", "BLANCO", "1293HMC", 2, "FLORINO", 95, 6.7, "2007/12/20"), 
("SDFSDFW034KM234", "ROJO", "0045DRA", 3, "MUSTANG", 220, 11.8, "2004/06/03"), 
("OKOKUH88NM9CC04", "NARANJA", "9392AAP", 4, "CLARITY", 135, 9.1, "2000/07/19"),
("KEIJNRJIJI39991", "ROJO", "8803ASF", 5, "VELOSTER", 95, 8.2, "2001/04/23"), 
("ASLOKOENREIRJI3", "NEGRO", "2267AAA", 6, "VENENO", 210, 10.3, "2000/01/01"), 
("KJUHMKIJWERLW23", "BLANCO", "8834GHI", 7, "MONTERO", 117, 10.0, "2004/07/23"), 
("OOKMKIJER394320", "AZUL", "2928CKT", 8, "ASTRA", 85, 7.2, "2006/10/11"), 
("KIEJRWERL222999", "GRIS", "7198BDS", 9, "ZOE", 95, 7.4, "2001/03/24"), 
("WASDASDASD92K39", "NEGRO", "0395FGP", 10, "ATECA", 85, 7.4, "2008/12/04"), 
("K3OK3ORK3ORK333", "AMARILLO", "4819CSI", 11, "VERSO", 110, 7.8, "2006/06/15"), 
("KEE22277ARDDC80", "BLANCO", "0000HBP", 12, "JETTA", 145, 9.3, "2009/12/19");



CREATE TABLE VEHICULO_COMPRA(
    BASTIDOR VARCHAR(30),
    PRECIO_VENTA DECIMAL(7,2),
    FECHA_VENTA DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_VEHICULO_COMPRA PRIMARY KEY (BASTIDOR),
    CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICULO_COMPRA FOREIGN KEY (BASTIDOR) REFERENCES VEHICULO(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO VEHICULO_COMPRA VALUES 
("JKSFLS23B342988", 12009.00, null), 
("JUUS234FWER23RW", 22029.99, "2014/08/12"), 
("KMOWEMFIF93223F", 19678.54, null), 
("FWEF232342AAAAA", 56999.02, null), 
("AAAA3AFKGUEG339", 12589.57, null), 
("PKOKI9UW45R233E", 89995.86, "2001/08/15"), 
("FERFFER34534533", 18954.59, "2014/02/04"), 
("XVXCV8X97XCV989", 10095.52, null),
("KH4578KROGKRO44", 14000.03, null), 
("LKJOGTUXTD34635", 15026.87, "2011/08/15"), 
("HGYUGMÑ35636531", 19584.33, "2013/09/11"), 
("LLSERASJK222823", 46000.00, "2002/08/13"), 
("KEYAO3242342020", 99999.60, null), 
("LKOJU234234234J", 24000.00, null), 
("OJIO2J34IOJ2423", 16023.23, "2013/01/05"), 
("JPKLKMKJH2U3424", 18000.00, null),
("MKNOKN38820020F", 18050.09, "2012/02/16"), 
("LKJAWE342422111", 64095.65, "2013/01/09"); 





CREATE TABLE VEHICULO_ALQUILER(
    BASTIDOR VARCHAR(30),
    PRECIO_ALQUILER DECIMAL(7,2),
    DISPONIBLE BOOLEAN,
    CONSTRAINT PK_VEHICULO_ALQUILER PRIMARY KEY (BASTIDOR),
    CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICULO_ALQUILER FOREIGN KEY (BASTIDOR) REFERENCES VEHICULO(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO VEHICULO_ALQUILER VALUES 
("JKSFLS23B342988", 560.57, false), 
("JUUS234FWER23RW", 330.33, true), 
("KMOWEMFIF93223F", 318.59, false), 
("FWEF232342AAAAA", 596.06, false), 
("AAAA3AFKGUEG339", 299.51, true), 
("PKOKI9UW45R233E", 750.09, true),
("FERFFER34534533", 311.80, true), 
("XVXCV8X97XCV989", 795.25, true),
("KH4578KROGKRO44", 300.03, true), 
("LKJOGTUXTD34635", 324.78, true), 
("HGYUGMÑ35636531", 316.31, true), 
("LLSERASJK222823", 602.25, false), 
("KEYAO3242342020", 705.98, false), 
("LKOJU234234234J", 380.58, false), 
("OJIO2J34IOJ2423", 301.84, true), 
("JPKLKMKJH2U3424", 300.96, false),
("MKNOKN38820020F", 301.99, true), 
("LKJAWE342422111", 794.84, false); 



CREATE TABLE ITV(
    BASTIDOR VARCHAR(30),
    FECHA DATE, 
    RESULTADO BOOLEAN,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ITV PRIMARY KEY (BASTIDOR, FECHA),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ITV FOREIGN KEY (BASTIDOR) REFERENCES VEHICULO_ALQUILER(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO ITV VALUES 
("JKSFLS23B342988", "2009/08/12", false), 
("JUUS234FWER23RW", "2009/08/11", true), 
("KMOWEMFIF93223F", "2003/05/08", true), 
("FWEF232342AAAAA", "2014/09/14", true), 
("AAAA3AFKGUEG339", "2011/04/10", false), 
("PKOKI9UW45R233E", "2005/08/11", true), 
("FERFFER34534533", "2001/11/18", false), 
("XVXCV8X97XCV989", "2006/08/08", false),
("KH4578KROGKRO44", "2009/08/11", true), 
("LKJOGTUXTD34635", "2013/05/13", false), 
("HGYUGMÑ35636531", "2014/04/25", true), 
("LLSERASJK222823", "2015/08/26", false), 
("KEYAO3242342020", "2016/08/02", false), 
("LKOJU234234234J", "2014/07/03", false), 
("OJIO2J34IOJ2423", "2012/07/05", true), 
("JPKLKMKJH2U3424", "2010/01/11", false),
("MKNOKN38820020F", "2007/04/10", true), 
("LKJAWE342422111", "2014/11/17", false); 






CREATE TABLE CLIENTES(
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(20),
    APELLIDOS VARCHAR(30),
    DNI VARCHAR(9),
    TLF_CONTACTO VARCHAR(12),
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(50),
    CIUDAD VARCHAR(30),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTES PRIMARY KEY (DNI) 
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTES VALUES 
("OSMAR", "MAZA LASTRA", "72089193V", "666002138", "C/ Renteria Reyes, 24", "SANTOÑA", "omaza1990@hotmail.com"), 
("RAFA", "MAZA MANTOS", "72084491L", "699002238", "C/ General Davila, 29", "REINOSA", "rafa_@hotmail.es"),  
("ERIK", "PEÑA MATA", "23089103F", "697804174", "C/ La Madrid, 09", "GAMA", "erik_pena_gamacity@gmail.com"), 
("DESI", "UNZUETA FERNANDEZ", "12345678D", "625036676", "C/ Suns Estados, 04", "CASTAÑEDA", "desi9328@outlook.com"), 
("ALEX", "PABLO LAVIN", "98745632A", "666012149", "C/ Brooklyn Nets, 11", "SUANCES", "alex__23@hotmail.es"), 
("NATALIA", "ARIAM SANTOS", "88552244T", "686678888", "C/ Genova Sill, 71", "NOJA", "nata_argos@hotmail.com"), 
("ALFREDO", "RUIZ CASTAÑOS", "14725863S", "616161236", "C/ Ruiz Carral, 34", "CORRALES", "alfredo_macaya@gmail.com"), 
("SUSANA", "ESCARLETA SOZ", "68451277S", "611443789", "C/ Alfonso Rey, 99", "CASTILLO", "susana_soz@hotmail.com"), 
("ADRIAN", "SANCHEZ ESPINOSA", "72089695X", "123456789", "C/ San Pantaleon, 99", "LAREDO", "adrian_laredo@hotmail.com"),  
("CARLOS", "RUIZ MATEOS", "13225217P", "664125877", "C/ Plaza San Antonio, 55", "MERUELO", "carlos__lines@hotmail.com"),
("IDALBA", "MAZA LASTRA", "72089192Q", "666002144", "C/ Renteria Reyes, 24", "SANTOÑA", "idalba__1988@hotmail.com"), 
("ANTONIO", "VALLE RISQUETO", "72086391T", "699442238", "C/ Paseo Pereda, 19", "SANTANDER", "k93k__tesoro@hotmail.com"),  
("SERGIO", "SANTOS MERINO", "24444100A", "697305574", "C/ Jesus de Monasterio, 12", "GAMA", "hay_que_ser_felizzzz@gmail.com"), 
("ALFREDO", "LILIETA MENENDEZ", "12345678S", "625136076", "C/ Avenida San Pedro, 85", "CASTRO", "alfre_liliiii@outlook.com"), 
("SARA", "SANCHEZ LAVIN", "68795632P", "66600214", "C/ Los Angeles, 10", "SOMO", "sara_albo_colin@hotmail.com"), 
("SOFIA", "ARIAM GOMEZ", "86052244T", "616678338", "C/ Gaditano Ole, 02", "GUEMES", "sofia_gran_hermano@hotmail.com"), 
("ROCIO", "RUIZ FERNANDEZ", "19925863P", "61616698", "C/ San Cristobal, 02", "CIRIEGO", "rociito_la_kuki@gmail.es"), 
("CARLOS ALBERTO", "RUIZ SAINZ", "68221277S", "611444777", "C/ Sigtes, 93", "CASTILLO", "carlos_ruizz@hotmail.com"), 
("IVAN", "ARGOS OCERIN", "72999695F", "103456759", "C/ Avenida Central, 29", "ISLA", "ivan_argos_gol@hotmail.es"),  
("SIRO", "ABAD MERINO", "99225217Z", "633125077", "C/ Plaza San Mateo, 53", "TORRELAVEGA", "siro__abad@hotmail.com");



CREATE TABLE CLIENTES_COMPRA(
    DNI VARCHAR(9),
    ID_VEHICULO VARCHAR(30),
    FECHA_COMPRA DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTES_COMPRA PRIMARY KEY (DNI, ID_VEHICULO, FECHA_COMPRA),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTES_COMPRA1 FOREIGN KEY (DNI) REFERENCES CLIENTES(DNI),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTES_COMPRA2 FOREIGN KEY (ID_VEHICULO) REFERENCES VEHICULO(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTES_COMPRA VALUES 
("72089193V", "JKSFLS23B342988", "2009/11/19"),
("72084491L", "JUUS234FWER23RW", "2009/12/13"),
("23089103F", "KMOWEMFIF93223F", "2009/05/11"),
("12345678D", "FWEF232342AAAAA", "2009/04/30"),
("98745632A", "AAAA3AFKGUEG339", "2005/01/02"), /* Falla */
("88552244T", "PKOKI9UW45R233E", "2008/01/13"),
("14725863S", "FERFFER34534533", "2004/11/06"),
("72089695X", "XVXCV8X97XCV989", "2012/11/06"),
("68451277S", "KH4578KROGKRO44", "2015/06/08"),
("12345678S", "KEYAO3242342020", "2009/05/19"),
("68795632P", "LKOJU234234234J", "2005/05/23"),
("86052244T", "LKJAWE342422111", "2003/09/23"),
("19925863P", "OJIO2J34IOJ2423", "2014/01/29"),
("68221277S", "JPKLKMKJH2U3424", "2014/02/21"),
("72089192Q", "MKNOKN38820020F", "2010/02/21");



CREATE TABLE CLIENTES_ALQUILER(
    DNI VARCHAR(9),
    ID_VEHICULO VARCHAR(30),
    FECHA_ALQUILER DATE,
    FECHA_ENTREGA_SUPUESTA DATE,
    FECHA_ENTREGA_REAL DATE, 
    FIANZA INT(4),
    ESTADO_DEVOLUCION VARCHAR(200),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTES_ALQUILER PRIMARY KEY (DNI, ID_VEHICULO, FECHA_ALQUILER),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTES_ALQUILER1 FOREIGN KEY (DNI) REFERENCES CLIENTES(DNI),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTES_ALQUIILER2 FOREIGN KEY (ID_VEHICULO) REFERENCES VEHICULO(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTES_ALQUILER VALUES 
("72089193V", "JKSFLS23B342988", "2009/09/19", "2009/12/19", "2009/12/19", 47, "Neumaticos desgastados."),
("72084491L", "JUUS234FWER23RW", "2011/06/28", "2011/06/29", "2011/06/29", 250, "Tiene la tapiceria estropeada."),
("23089103F", "KMOWEMFIF93223F", "2008/12/01", "2008/12/19", "2008/12/21", 290, null),
("12345678D", "FWEF232342AAAAA", "2003/09/10", "2003/09/11", "2003/09/20", 199, null),
("98745632A", "AAAA3AFKGUEG339", "2003/09/02", "2003/09/19", "2003/09/19", 300, null),
("88552244T", "PKOKI9UW45R233E", "2002/12/09", "2002/12/19", "2002/12/19", 267, true),
("14725863S", "FERFFER34534533", "2002/09/10", "2002/09/19", "2002/09/26", 136, "Mal funcionamiento del aire acondicionado."),
("72089695X", "XVXCV8X97XCV989", "2005/09/06", "2005/09/09", "2005/09/10", 68, null);



CREATE TABLE PENALIZACION(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DIAS INT,
    IMPORTE DECIMAL(7,2),
    CONSTRAINT PK_PENALIZACION PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
);

INSERT INTO PENALIZACION (DIAS, IMPORTE) VALUES 
(2,39.45), 
(5,74.62), 
(10,128.41), 
(14,274.62), 
(21,409.03), 
(28,589.99), 
(30,602.71);
```

Comment: Creo que phpMyAdmin tiene un cuadro donde muestra el historial de queries ejecutados. ¿Puedes revisarlo y colocar el query que ha intentado ejecutar?

Comment: Podrias poner todo el .sql?

Comment: Lo mas seguro que lo obtengo de otra base de datos, no olvides inclur antes el use database

Comment: Actualizada la pregunta con el .sql

Comment: ya inclui el "use"... revisad el código completo.

Comment: Muestra un ScreenShot del error

Comment: El error es el incluido anteriormente:  #1054 - Unknown column 'FOTO' in 'order clause' en una ventana emergente

Comment: No tuve ningun error ejecuandolo http://i.imgur.com/aI1tgVy.png ¿Habría algo más que creas estar pasando?

Comment: No creo nada más. Sólo ejecuto/importo ese .sql y listo. Y al hacer click en "vehiculo" para ver los datos de la tabla, me sale ese error. A mi también me las inserta (hasta las de vehiculo), prueba a hacer click sobre los datos de esa tabla.

Comment: ¿A qué se debe este problema cuando en ninguna parte de la SQL tengo la palabra/columna "FOTO"?

Comment: ¿Sigues con el mismo problema? Te lo comento porque he probado el script tal cual lo has dejado y me funciona sin problemas. No consigo reproducir el error que comentas.

Comment: Ya me funciona. En el mismo PC me da el error ese no sé porque igual algun "bug" o registro guardado en la CPU, pero en otros PCs me funciona sin problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Puede que antes existiese ese campo? Te lo comento porque phpmyadmin cachea información de las tablas. Si quieres puede vaciar la caché y ver si se resuelve el problema:

Pincha en la tabla -> Pestaña Operaciones -> Sección Mantenimiento de la tabla -> Vaciar la caché

Espero que esto te sirva.

Comment: Ya no tengo ese error pero gracias.

Comment: @omaza1990 Deberías agregar una respuesta propia con el proceso con el que lo resolviste.